# "invariant expected app router to be mounted" on Storybook running for Nextjs 13 (AppDir)

Tags: storybook, next.js13

I'm running some Nextjs 13 (App Dir) components on storybook but, when I import anything from "next/navigation" i.e.

`import {redirect} from "next/navigation";`

gives this error on storybook:

> invariant expected app router to be mounted

Now, we know that nextjs docs tell us to use "next/navigation" instead of the previous "next/router" in the app dir. Changing back to "next/router" removes the error on storybook and the component successfully mounts.

I don't want to keep changing this back and forth to work on storybook as I'm frequently using Storybook as well as NextJS builds.